# Bash- txt to column

Tags: text-processing, command-line, csv

I need to merge three txt files into one csv file, in which the first txt file goes to the first column, the second txt file goes to the second column, and the third txt to the third column.

The number of items in each column is not similar.

How to do it in bash.

Comment: Please provide sample input from all three files and a sample of what you would like the output to look like.

Comment: Ok..I really don't know how to enter my sample here.

Comment: Sorry, This is my first time being here..

Comment: Do you want each word in the text files to be in one column, or the lines? What happens when the first txt file is finished, but the other ones aren't? Discard it, or leave the associated columns empty? It would be great if you could imagine what you would want to have at a smaller scale (maybe 10 lines) and post it here.

Comment: I do know how my final file would be.
each file has 5 columns and different number of rows.
but I want each file (with all it's columns) to go to one cell. and the next file goes  to next column (in one cell).

Comment: I didn't put this on hold, but that comment really makes things way more unclear. Your question body says you want each file to be treated as a column, but now you say, if I understood you right, that each file has multiple columns and you want the resulting file to contain 1 row with the first cell holding the whole first file "(with all its columns)", the second cell holding the whole second file "(with all its columns)", etc. That's so bizarre, there must be a misunderstanding. I can see 3 different interpretations here.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the lines of each file are valid as CSV fields, it should just be a matter  of doing:

```
paste -d , file1 file2 file3 > output.csv
```

If `file1` contains `x`, `file2` `y` and `file3` `z`, you'd get `x,y,z` in output.csv. To get `"x","y","z"`, you can change it to:

```
paste -d '"",' - file1 - - file2 - - file3 - < /dev/null > output.csv
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems it doesn't recognize my file1

Comment: @Mona, my bet would be that your files have MS-DOS line-endings. Try converting them to Unix format first with dos2unix or pipe the output of `paste` to `tr -d '\r'` to remove the spurious CR characters.